# A very simple math puzzle: An object O weights 1 N and the half of the weight of object O. What is the weight of object O?

Tags: puzzle

So, today I came across a very simple (or so I though) math puzzle. If this is the wrong StackExchange please point me to the right place to ask.

The puzzle goes as such:

> An object O weights 1 N and the half of the weight of object O. What is the weight of object O?

Of course, I formulated the following equation:
$ W_O=1N + 0.5W_O $, so $ W_O = 2N $

My stupid question, as I am in no way a mathematician, is: Is that above equation a correct mathematical representation of said puzzle? If not, what would be the correct mathematical formulation? Is the answer $ 2N $ correct?

Comment: Yes, $2N$ is the correct answer.

Comment: Well, mind posting it as an answer (perhaps with a little bit of explanation) so that I can accept it then?

Comment: What am going to write there - "yes"?

Comment: Well, as a non-mathematician I struggle with the concept of "Some thing of unknown weight plus 1 and the half of some unknown weight equals some known weight". Perhaps you could offer some real world analogy or some other kind of colorful explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ denote the weight of the object, hence $x=N+\frac12x$.

Subtract $\frac12x$ from each side of the equation, hence $\frac12x=N$.

Multiply each side of the equation by $2$, hence $x=2N$.

Therefore, the weight of the object (denoted by $x$) is $2N$.